# Add item to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

This is probably a stupidly easy question, but I'm suffering from brainfade ... I'm using a SELECT statement to pull data from a MySQL Database then looping through it with a WHILE loop to push the returned data to the array '$arr', using the code below;

```
$query="SELECT idBaptism as id, baptismDate as eventDate, concat(baptismForename,' ',baptismSurname) as name, churchName, tbLocation.idLocation as locationid, location, clat as lat, clng as lng FROM tbBaptism, tbLocation, tbChurch WHERE tbBaptism.idLocation=tbLocation.idLocation AND tbBaptism.idChurch=tbChurch.idChurch";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
```

My question is I want to append the text 'Baptism' onto the end of each row of the array, what's the easiest way to do this??

As an example, here is the sample output of two rows of the array produced from the code above using print_r;

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventDate] => 1874-03-08 [name] => Henry Stanley [churchName] => St. Leonards [locationid] => 28 [location] => Halwell, Devon, UK [lat] => 50.366001 [lng] => -3.720500 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventDate] => 1870-11-06 [name] => Valentine Joles [churchName] => St. John The Evangelist [locationid] => 27 [location] => East Horrington, Somerset, UK [lat] => 51.218143 [lng] => -2.600683 )
```

I want to add value pair on the end of each row, such as [type] => 'Baptism' ...

Comment: Can you add the sample output?

Comment: $arr[] = $row."Baptism"; You need this?

Comment: running a print_r to display the output of the array, I get this (example 2 returned array row); Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventDate] => 1874-03-08 [name] => Henry Stanley [churchName] => St. Leonards [locationid] => 28 [location] => Halwell, Devon, UK [lat] => 50.366001 [lng] => -3.720500 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventDate] => 1870-11-06 [name] => Valentine Joles [churchName] => St. John The Evangelist [locationid] => 27 [location] => East Horrington, Somerset, UK [lat] => 51.218143 [lng] => -2.600683 ) but I want to add another entry manually on the end, such as [type] => Baptism

Comment: `$arr['type'] = 'Baptism';`

Comment: That was my logical thinking also @splash58 but if I add that into the WHILE loop after $arr[] = $row; it doesn't work!!

Comment: do yu want and it for each inner array?

Comment: `$arr[] = $row + array('type'=>'Baptism');`

Comment: yes exactly @splash58, it needs to be inside of each array row

Comment: Thank you @splash ... that code works, it's a simple thing, but you've just made my day a lot easier!!!!

Comment: The easiest way to do that is in your query preferably `'Baptism' as type` define the column and value directly into the query.

Comment: I thought about doing that @Alex, but it seemed wasteful having a column like that in the database, when I can just append something on the end of an array in PHP. I think (I may be wrong?) that this is the lessor of two evils in processing overheads ... EDIT: Okay, I see what you mean and you may well be right!

Comment: @Gary you wanted the easiest way...

Answer (score 0):

Simply push the new element to the fetched array `$row` and then push it to the array `$arr`, like this:

```
// your code

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $row['type'] = 'Baptism';
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
```